# How can I know if a host belongs to group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory with all the hosts I need.
I've organized the inventory using a `hosts.yml` where I specify the groups the hosts belong to:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
    host3:
    host4:
    host5:
  children:
    group1:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:
    group2:
      hosts:
        host2:
        host3:
```

I'd like to have an ansible command to run in a script to know whether a host belongs to a group or another, in order to decide what to do next. I'd like to to this statically, **before** trying to connect to the host and gather the facts.

Is there any ansible command I could use?

Or maybe I have to change the approach and add the information I need to the single host's yml?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way of doing this is to write your play to only target the specific group. If you have a play that looks like:

```
- hosts: group1
  tasks:
    ...
```

...you know that it will only run on hosts in `group1`.

---

If you have a play targeting multiple groups, and you want to have group-specific behavior for a single task (and you can't factor that out into its own play), you can check if a hostname is `in` a group:

```
- name: do something only if the current host is in group1
  debug:
    msg: "Look at me I'm in group1"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups.group1
```

Comment: thank you for your reply :-) 
I don't know if I'm doing right but I'd like to know if a host belong to a group before launching any playbook in order to set-up some stuff before. I've this information in the inventory (in the form of a membership to a group but I could arrange it differently) and I'm wondering if I could use it or not. 
I'm not sure I'm on the right path...

Comment: It really seems like you should be doing this in the context of playbook and let Ansible worry about inventory parsing. You can suppress fact gathering in a play by setting `gather_facts: false`, so you can run commands before connecting to the remote host.